# Calculate confidance in openCV EigenFaceRecognizer

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying openCV EigenFaceRecognizer example given [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_save_load.html).

I have successfully recognized the face and predictedLabel is correct. But I wish to know how much confidant the program is about the prediction. I have tried [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10825886/) but values seems like garbage(like 1547139552). Can anyone please help in calculating the confidence level.

Comment: You should put at least the code sections that are important in the question!

Comment: [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10831372/) is my function that recognizes the face.